# Migrating from StackExchangeRedisCacheClient to RedisCacheClient

Tags: c#, .net, stackexchange.redis, redis-cache

I am building a project based on **StackExchangeRedisCacheClient** and obsolete has popped out:
'StackExchangeRedisCacheClient' is obsolete: 'This interface will be removed with the next major. Please use RedisCacheClient instead.'

so i'm trying to move from **StackExchangeRedisCacheClient** to **RedisCacheClient**
unfortunately there is no documentation or some helpful info for doing that.

how do i create a cache client? with **RedisCacheClient** ? the require args are 'RedisCacheClient(**IRedisCacheConnectionPoolManager**, **ISerializer**, **RedisConfiguration**)'

i have looked at the following link and tried to implement a Single pool with no success https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/issues/176#
couldn't create a cacheClient after providing the connection string.

**StackExchangeRedisCacheClient:**(works fine)

```
  public CacheManager()
    {
        string connectionString = "localhost:300....."
        var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
        cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(serializer, connectionString);
        clientName = cacheClient.Database.Multiplexer.ClientName;

    }
```

**RedisCacheClient:**

```
  public CacheManager()
    {
        string connectionString = "localhost:300....."
        var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
        cacheClient = new RedisCacheClient( *** ??? *** );
        clientName = cacheClient.Database.Multiplexer.ClientName;

    }
```

Comment: Do you found any other solution for this?

Comment: im also looking for best solution.. anyone?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/issues/176 if you don't care about having multiple connections you can use the following class:

```
internal class SinglePool : IRedisCacheConnectionPoolManager
    {
        private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer connection;

        public SinglePool(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        }

        public IConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection()
        {
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if i care about mutiple connection ? how to use static?